# Unable to Compare 2 DateTime, from CRM and Excel

Tags: c#, datetime, crm

I encountered issue comparing `DateTime` values from `CRM` and `Excel`.

```
1. DateTime excelDT1 = Convert.ToDateTime(row[Excel.notificationdate].ToString().Trim(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat); ;
2. var excelDT2 = row[Excel.notificationdate].ToString().Trim();
3. var excelDT3 = row[Excel.notificationdate];

4. DateTime crmDT1 = Convert.ToDateTime(caseEntity.Attributes[Case.notificationdate].ToString().Trim(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat); ;
5. var crmDT2 = caseEntity.Attributes[Case.notificationdate].ToString().Trim();
6. var crmDT3 = caseEntity.Attributes[Case.notificationdate];
```

Below are the outputs respectively:

> 1. excelDT1: 1/13/2020 12:00:00 AM
> 2. excelDT2: 13/01/2020
> 3. excelDT3: 13/01/2020
>
>    ---
> 4. crmDT1: 12/1/2020 4:00:00 PM
> 5. crmDT2: 1/12/2020 4:00:00 PM
> 6. crmDT3: 1/12/2020 4:00:00 PM

May I know how can I format the above such that they can be checked if they are `equal`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare 1st and 4th with `public static bool Equals (DateTime t1, DateTime t2);`

```
var result = DateTime.Equals(excelDT1, crmDT1);
```